# ReordableListView remove child Tap gesture in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to make a ReordableListView containing several ExpansionTile but it doesn't work, the ExpansionTile doesn't open.

If I put the parameter **buildDefaultDragHandles: false** the ExpansionTile opens but the gesture for reordering the list no longer works.

How can I join the reorder gesture with ExpansionTile without affecting each other?

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({super.key});

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: ReorderableListView.builder(
          //buildDefaultDragHandles: false,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ExpansionTile(
              key: GlobalKey(),
              title: Container(
                height: 70.0,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 30.0,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
          itemCount: 10,
          onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering it would work if you wrap the container with a Dismissible widget so that you can swipe to remove the item

```
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  final item = items[index];
  return Dismissible(
    // Each Dismissible must contain a Key. Keys allow Flutter to
    // uniquely identify widgets.
    key: Key(item),
    // Provide a function that tells the app
    // what to do after an item has been swiped away.
    onDismissed: (direction) {
      // Remove the item from the data source.
      setState(() {
        items.removeAt(index);
      });

      // Then show a snackbar.
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('$item dismissed')));
    },
    child: ListTile(
      title: Text(item),
    ),
  );
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Having ExpansionTile leading and `ReorderableListView` handler at same place is kinda bad ux i think, you can have it like row or change one to the leading

You can do

```dart
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  return ExpansionTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
    key: GlobalKey(),
    title: Container(
      height: 70.0,
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
    children: [
      Container(
        height: 30.0,
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
    ],
  );
},
```